# Web Based .NET Browser Canvas Share

Tags: .net, html, canvas, share, synchronization

I want to share my HTML5 canvas of 1 user to another invited user. It should be real time syncing like screen share. What ever user A draw, it should reflect same as it's being written on user B's canvas.

Can you please help me how to do this in .NET?

Thanks alot

Comment: How are you planning to communicate the contents of the canvas to the other user?

Comment: So A's drawings show on B's canvas and not reversed--so B will not be issuing drawing commands?  As for communications, SignalR works well to deliver serialized canvas drawing commands among remote clients through a hub server.

Comment: yes. Only A will write and B will watch

Comment: Here's a link to an example that uses SignalR to broadcast serialized html5 Canvas line-path commands to remote clients connected through the SignalR Hub: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417502/Online-Whiteboard-using-HTML-and-SignalR